# gganimate line plot for dates and counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create an animated line plot that overall looks like this:

[image: Plot Image]

I think this looks a bit cluttered, and would like to show the top 3 regions at any given date as the plot "progresses" once animated. In other words, I would like to see only the top 3 regions with the highest counts for every date.

Here is a sample of my data that I used to create this plot:

```
      Date Region1 Region2 Region3 Region4 Region5
2020-04-01     656    1095    1198    1010    1211
2020-04-02     423    1066    1189    1033    1366
2020-04-03     536    1159    1396    1437    1899
2020-04-04    1328    1229    1804    1322    1947
2020-04-05     595    1053    1054    1052    1322
2020-04-06     694     959    1144    1218    1697
2020-04-07     781    1021    1177     994    1707
2020-04-08    1011    1278    1203    1938    1408
2020-04-09     895    1166    1312    1592    1504
2020-04-10    1057    1368    1321    1372    1551
```

Here is the code I used to make the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x = Date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x[, 2], color = "Region1"), size = 1.25, show.legend = T) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x[, 3], color = "Region2"), size = 1.25) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x[, 4], color = "Region3"), size = 1.25) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x[, 5], color = "Region4"), size = 1.25) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x[, 6], color = "Region5"), size = 1.25) +
    ggtitle("Regions With Most Cases") +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d") +
    ylab("Number of Cases") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('Region1' = 'steelblue', 'Region2' = 'darkred', 'Region3' = 'darkorchid3', 'Region4' = 'burlywood', 'Region5' = 'darkgreen')) +
    labs(color = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") 
    # + transition_reveal(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, the following code:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Region1:Region5) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Rank = rank(-value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  ggplot(.) + 
    geom_path(aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = ifelse(Rank <= 3, name, "Hide"), group = name)) + 
    ggtitle("Regions With Most Cases") +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2500)) + 
    ylab("Number of Cases") +
    scale_color_manual(
      values = c('Region1' = 'steelblue',  'Region2' = 'darkred', 
                 'Region3' = 'darkorchid3','Region4' = 'burlywood', 
                 'Region5' = 'darkgreen',     'Hide' = NA),
      breaks = c('Region1', 'Region2', 'Region3', 'Region4', 'Region5')) +
    labs(color = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
    transition_reveal(Date)
```

produces this chart:

[image]